# How to constantly get the x-position of an moving object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-event, viewdidload, touchesbegan

I have to buttons `leftbutton, rightbutton` both of them being `SKSpriteNode()`.
When the user touches one of the buttons, there is a little ship that moves left and right as long as the user holds the touch.

Now I need a function or anything else that gives me the `ship.position.x` the whole time. I am stuck to try to make it print the position constantly. I can make it print everytime the button is touched but it only prints it once.

In my `didMove` I only created the buttons and the ship. So it should be rather irrelevant.

```
func moveShip (moveBy: CGFloat, forTheKey: String) {
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: moveBy, y: 0, duration: 0.09)
    let repeatForEver = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
    let movingSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, repeatForEver])
    ship.run(movingSequence, withKey: forTheKey)
} 

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("\(ship.position.x)")

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let pointTouched = touch.location(in: self)

        if leftButton.contains(pointTouched) {

//          !! I MAKE IT PRINT THE POSITION HERE !!

            moveShip(moveBy: -30, forTheKey: "leftButton")
        }

        else if rightButton.contains(pointTouched) {
            moveShip(moveBy: 30, forTheKey: "rightButton")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first{
        let pos = touch.location(in: self)
        let node = self.atPoint(pos)

        if node == aButton {

        } else {
            ship.removeAction(forKey: "leftButton")
            ship.removeAction(forKey: "rightButton")
        }
    }
}
```

In my code, the position is only printed once at the beginning of the touch and not printed until you release the touch and touch it again. Is there a possible way to do this with my code?

Comment: You can override an update method. In this method you should be able to get your object and get is position!

Comment: Ive read much about this update method. How can I override it? When I try, there is no update method suggested by xCode

Comment: Have a look at Bharath answer!

Comment: only works when I move the finger but when I hold it without moving, the ship moves constantly but the position is only printed once in the beginning..

Comment: Maybe you can set a timer that call a function every 0.1 second, and this function, reset the timer, it would create a loop? When you remove your finger, you just stop the timer

Comment: I could give that a try. Where would you call the function. In the didMove function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **touchesMoved** function won't help you with your particular problem. You can check your frame constantly by creating a `var timer = Timer()` as instance variable.

You then have to set up the timer and the function that is called when a specific amount of time is over.
Do as following in your **`didMove`** function:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, 
        selector: #selector(detectShipPosition), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

As this will repeat itself every 0.01 seconds it will call the function `detectShipPosition` which you will implement **OUTSIDE** **didMove**.

```
func detectShipPosition(){
    print("\(ship.position.x)")
}
```

Comment: just tried this, and it worked. had the idea to use the timer but was not getting the "selector" bit. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can make use of the **touchesMoved** delegate method(It tells the responder when one or more touches associated with an event changed.) as follows,

```
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("\(ship.position.x)")
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it does print the position when I move the finger. But when I hold the left button and do not move my finger but hold the button, it does not print the x position constantly..

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the comment you posted on Bharath answer.

You can change below with your own value:

```
longGesture.minimumPressDuration
```

You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var leftButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let longGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPress(_:)))
        longGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        longGesture.delegate = self
        leftButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

        rightButton.addGestureRecognizer(longGesture)

    }

    @objc func longPress(_ gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        print("\(ship.position.x)")
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds really nice. but trying to implement it, it give me the error that leftButton has no member "addGestureRecognizer()". I think it is because my leftButton is an SKSpriteNode not a Button.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the update() function in your scene, it will be called for every frame and you can check your object's position (and existence) in there to print the value when it changes:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) 
{
    if let ship = theShipSprite,
       ship.position != lastPosition
    {
       print(ship.position) // or whatever it is you need to do
       lastPosition = shipPosition
    }
}
```